# How can I practice DDD on my own without access to a domain expert?

Tags: domain-driven-design, software-design, business-logic, methodology

I'm trying to learn DDD, I see it have a lot of potential and I want to apply it and bring it to my company. But I am currently away on leave so don't have access to a business expert. How could I practice it without that access? Is it even possible? I have read the blue book and done Julie Lerman DDD pluralsight course but still I feel hands on experience eludes me. Is building an app using the tactical patterns while being conscious of using the same language enough?

Tried tutorials and did a pluralsight course.

Answer (score 1):

Build a system that models something you are familiar. Some ideas:

- A todo list system with deadlines and reminders. Trivial, but good to get the basics.
- A university-like course management system. Some modules depend on other modules (so a student cannot enroll unless they have completed the previous module).
- An online shop, including stock, warehouse and fullfilment management.

And get a copy of [Implementing Domain-Driven Design](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/implementing-domain-driven-design/9780133039900/) or [Domain Modeling Made Functional](https://pragprog.com/titles/swdddf/domain-modeling-made-functional/) depending if you want to do OO or FP DDD.

You probably won't experience a lot of the problems around ubiquitous language as they pop up when more than one person starts discussing a problem/domain.

Answer (score 0):

No, it takes time to learn DDD. There is no one correct way. Everyone does DDD little differently.

Try look at this repository: https://gitlab.com/food-delivery5161742/commerce
There is used DDD + hexagonal architecture.

Only thing missing in there are domain events, such as "order.created," etc.